Deprecated default checkbox but what is the replacement?
I have this code and as you see, ngModel there is deprecated

I also tried this from this web page but then my checkbox is not checked:

I then tried [checked]="checked" which also is not working. What is the correct replacement/upgrade that works?

Why do you have both [(ngModel)] and [formControlName] on your checkbox? You are mixing reactive forms and template-driven forms. You should only use one of these. Where does the checked come from? Is it an input of the component?

@JSONDerulo angular/material is where mat-checkbox comes from and I could not get it to work without adding [(ngModel)]="checked".   I would LOVE to remove the [(ngModel)]="checked" but then my checkbox is not checked by default when the user lands on the page which is desired.  Then they can change it after that.
